# Can I see who is tethered to my hotspot?

Tags: iphone, security, tethering

Long story short - I have to tether at home for a few months.

I have noticed my green icon flashing up while nothing of mine is connected (100% not mine). I'm a bit nervous that others are using basic dictionary attempts to connect. Change the password regularly. (Yes I could implement better security, but for a hotspot.. )

With Android I used to be able to see the list of connected devices. I haven't figured out with Apple.

My question: Is there a built in way of seeing "What is connected to your hotspot" - I'm not looking for info on it, and not interested to run a network scan on myself each time. I would just appreciate a way to see "A B C is connected"

Is there a way out of the box I'm missing ?

iPhone 11. Updated to latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you'd need third party apps for that

Source: [Find out what devices are connected to your iPhone’s Personal Hotspot](https://appletoolbox.com/find-out-what-devices-are-connected-to-your-iphones-personal-hotspot/)

#### How can I see what devices are connected to my iPhone?

> A blue notification on your iPhone tells you when someone is using your Personal Hotspot. But it doesn’t tell you who that person is. To find out what devices are connecting to the Personal Hotspot on your iPhone you need to use third-party apps instead.

> But iOS doesn’t offer any way to find out exactly who is connected to your Personal Hotspot. For that, you need to install a network scanning app instead.

> Open Network Analyzer and select the LAN tab at the bottom of the screen. Tap the Scan button to scan your current network for all the devices connected to it. If someone is connected to your iPhone’s Personal Hotspot, it turns back all the devices using your cellular data.
> Unfortunately, network scanners can’t show you the device names for who’s using your Personal Hotspot. But they can tell you every IP and MAC address for those devices. Sometimes, Network Analyzer also tells you if those connections come from an Apple device or not.

[Network Analyzer for iOS (Free)](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/network-analyzer/id562315041)

---

> iOS doesn’t show you what devices are connected to your Personal Hotspot right now, but you can find out who has connected to your hotspot recently using the Cellular settings on your iPhone.

> Open the Settings app and tap on Cellular. Scroll down to the Cellular Data section that lists all the apps that have used your data. Tap Personal Hotspot to see the device names and data usage for everyone who has used your iPhone’s Personal Hotspot.

---

#### How do I kick someone off my iPhone’s Personal Hotspot?

> *Don’t allow others to join in the Settings*
>
> 1. Open the Settings on your iPhone and go to the Personal Hotspot page.
> 2. Turn off the option to Allow Others to Join.
> 3. You can also stop your family members from connecting to your iPhone’s Personal Hotspot by turning off the Family Sharing option.